# How to estimate the VM resources (CPU, RAM, HDD etc) with respect to Docker image size? My images are huge, 5-10 GB

Tags: linux, docker, size, virtual-machine

I've to host Docker containers on a Linux VM. How to estimate the VM resources (CPU, RAM, HDD etc) with respect to image size? My images are huge, 5-10 GB. Is there a formula (or may be a thumb rule) to estimate?

Comment: How do you get images that are so large? Can you post a couple of your Dockerfiles?

Comment: I've created Siebel image by manually installing Siebel on a base image. This is a PoC activity so I'm not concerned about support and license related aspects of it at this moment. I committed the container post installation. Although there are some configurations still due but I'll sort it out later. But I've to estimate the resources needed on VM.

Comment: I also want to understand the way a container is loaded into memory. Whether the entire container is loaded into memory or partially? If partially, then what components goes to memory and what remains on disk. I'm unable to find any document explaining this aspect of containers.